# Cubic Bezier Path—preserve arc length while straighten it

Tags: math, bezier, cubic-bezier

I would like to »straighten« a cubic bezier path, such that its arc length is preserved.

[image]

The coordinates of `A`, `B` and their control Points (`C` and `D`) are given, as well as their destinations (`A'` and `B'`). So while animating `A` to `A'` and `B` to `B'` I need to calculate values for `C` and `D` as well, to make the line appear equally long.

As described [here](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#arclength) for the arc length:

> for cubic and higher Bézier curves, there is no way to solve this function if you want to use it "for all possible coordinates".

Has anybody come over that before?

Comment: If you don't need the length to stay *exactly* invariant, you could simply move `A, B, C, D` in a straight line towards their target points.

Comment: Which way should `C,D` take? They could fall together with `A'` and `B'`… Is there any approximation how big the »error« could be?

Comment: Your formulation is slightly confusing: if `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `A'` and `B'` are given, what is missing?

Comment: `C` and `D` over time, such that the arc length always stays the same.